# AngularJS $http request hide Authorization header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authorization, http-get

I my AngularJS function, I make $http GET request with a list of header.
And one of them is really secret one: Authorization. How can I hide it from the user?

```
$scope.SearchCar = function () {
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic code.to.hide',
        'Host': 'some.host.com'
    }
}
var url = 'https://some.host.com/car?q=' + $scope.carName;

$http.get(url, config)
    .then(function (response) {
        //success
    },
    function (response) {
        //failure
    }).finally(function () {
        //finally
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't. Use a server backend to create a unique header that you can validate when you receive the request.

Comment: In this case I need to make a call to my api, and user can inspect the endpoint and just get the key by invoking it manually. Am I right?